# How do I determine radio button selection based on value using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button, webdriver

I am trying to determine which of two radio buttons is selected and based on that select the other one.   I'm using Java and selenium.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="row span-670px">
<h3>Turn on</h3>
<div class="field-row">
    <div class="field-wrap radio-row clearfix ">
        <input type="radio" name="choosePaymentModel" value="QUOTEHOLD" checked="checked" />
        <label>
            ...
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row last span-670px">
<h3>Turn off</h3>
<div class="field-row">
    <div class="field-wrap radio-row clearfix ">
        <input type="radio" name="choosePaymentModel" value="BASIC"  />
        <label>
            ...
        </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing that differs is the value attribute.  The checked attribute will change based on which one is checked, so the only clear way to differentiate the two is by value.  I can't seem to find the proper syntax to grab the correct radio buttons.  When utilizing the IDE, the element identifiers swap out with each other depending on the selection so nothing is every unique.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='choosePaymentModel' and @value='QUOTEHOLD']"));
```

and

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='choosePaymentModel' and @value='BASIC']"));
```

to determine which was selected, but unfortunately the click methods did not work on them.

When playing with the IDE was lucky enough to find two separately bizzare elements to click on, which were not in fact elements that contained the "isSelected" values.

In either case, looks like I found the answer to my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String tempvalue[]=object.split(Concrete.VALUE_SPLIT);
//here I am splitting the values passed through data sheet against radio buttons                
String Val_radio =Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(tempvalue[0])+data+OR.getProperty(tempvalue[1]))).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(Val_radio);
Boolean radio = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='radio' and @value="+"'"+Val_radio+"'"+"]")).isSelected();
if(radio.booleanValue()==true){

//do something here

}
```